# Not sure how to decode log event where I can't get the ABI for the contract?

Tags: abi

I am trying to decode some transactions logs and have hit a problem with one of the entries.  In the event log for [0x1c50c336329a7ee41f722ce5d848ebd066b72bf44a1eaafcaa92e8c0282049d2](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1c50c336329a7ee41f722ce5d848ebd066b72bf44a1eaafcaa92e8c0282049d2#eventlog) the first three events are a transfer, a deposit, and a transfer.  The fourth one (# 488) refers to the *UniswapV3Pool*
contract [0xf4ad61db72f114be877e87d62dc5e7bd52df4d9b](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf4ad61db72f114be877e87d62dc5e7bd52df4d9b), for which I can't retrieve the ABI information.  When I try it via the Etherscan API, I get back:

```
{
    status: "0",
    message: "NOTOK",
    result: "Contract source code not verified"
}
```

Since the Etherscan.io summary provides sane data in respect of this entry, I assume that Etherscan had some way of getting the ABI information?

I am obviously missing something!

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The four entry has topic `0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67`.

Using the [Ethereum Signature Database](https://www.4byte.directory) we get it refers to the event

```
Swap(address,address,int256,int256,uint160,uint128,int24)
```

Looking at the verified source on Etherscan it is declared as

```
/// @notice Emitted by the pool for any swaps between token0 and token1
/// @param sender The address that initiated the swap call, and that received the callback
/// @param recipient The address that received the output of the swap
/// @param amount0 The delta of the token0 balance of the pool
/// @param amount1 The delta of the token1 balance of the pool
/// @param sqrtPriceX96 The sqrt(price) of the pool after the swap, as a Q64.96
/// @param liquidity The liquidity of the pool after the swap
/// @param tick The log base 1.0001 of price of the pool after the swap
event Swap(
    address indexed sender,
    address indexed recipient,
    int256 amount0,
    int256 amount1,
    uint160 sqrtPriceX96,
    uint128 liquidity,
    int24 tick
);
```

---

To read from 4bytes directory

```
curl -X GET https://www.4byte.directory/api/v1/event-signatures/?hex_signature=0xc42079f94a6350d7e6235f29174924f928cc2ac818eb64fed8004e115fbcca67
```

Comment: Thanks @Ismael.

Apologies for being a bit slow with this but I can't seem to get the lookup to work.

My understanding is that I should be able to get the signature by providing the topic as follows:

https://www.4byte.directory/api/v1/signatures/?hex_signature=0xc42079f9

Likewise, I should be able to go the other way and generate the topic as follows:

https://www.4byte.directory/api/v1/signatures/?text_signature=Swap(address,address,int256,int256,uint160,uint128,int24)

However, neither works.  Can you advise the URL you used to lookup the hex signature?

Comment: @user3115148 I've added the `curl` command that can be used to retrieve the event signature. Events signatures are 32 bytes in length.

Comment: event-signatures, not just “signature” in your url will fix it

Comment: How did Etherscan figure out about this Swap() function? Do they use Ethereum Signature Database also?

Comment: How programmatically get that function under `Looking at the verified source on Etherscan it is declared as`?

Comment: @sirjay Please, create a new question instead of using comments that way it will be more visible. You can add a link to this question if it helps to set the context.